# Reading n number and compare in pascal

Tags: pascal

I am going to write a program that asks the user to enter "n" number and then compare number to find 2th largest number i used while:

```
while i>n do read(number); i:=i+1;
```

is that true? how to save number and compare them?
for ex if user have 4 number save them like this:

> a:=number1;
>   b:=number2; ...

Comment: your question is incomprehensible, please rephrase

Comment: Also, you have to think your algorithm. If I tell you a bunch of numbers and ask you to tell me the smallest, you don't need to remember them all, you just have to keep track of the smallest one.

Comment: Have you had any classes, read any books, or done any tutorials in Pascal at all?

Comment: Your code is totally flawed. `while i > n` is backward (it should be `<= n`). You should find a tutorial on Pascal and work your way through it. (The easiest solution for needing to keep a list of numbers when you don't know ahead of time how many would be an array; the tutorial will show you how to declare and use it.)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for finding the second largest number from a set (assuming that's what you're after) is relatively simple.

```
get number into ultimate, on end-of-file exit
get number into penult, on end-of-file exit
if penult is greater than ultimate:
    swap ultimate and penult

while true:
    get number into num, on end-of-file return penult
    if num is greater than ultimate:
        set penult to ultimate
        set ultimate to num
    else:
        if num is greater than penult:
            set penult to num
```

In other words, keep a "list" of the top two numbers `[ultimate, penult]` and slot each coming number into that list if it turns out to belong there.

Once you run out of numbers, the second item of that list is the second highest number from the entire set.

On the off-chance that you don't want duplicates taking up both slots (such as `1,2,1` giving you `1` as the second highest where you really want `2`), you can throw away those duplicates if they match:

```
get number into ultimate, on end-of-file exit
set penult to ultimate
while penult is equal to ultimate:
    get number into penult, on end-of-file exit
if penult is greater than ultimate:
    swap ultimate and penult

while true:
    get number into num, on end-of-file return penult
    if num is greater than ultimate:
        set penult to ultimate
        set ultimate to num
    else:
        if num is greater than penult and num is not equal to ultimate:
            set penult to testnum
```

Rewriting that in Pascal, I'll leave as an exercise for you, since it may well be classwork.